# How to Publish Test Result from One Project to Another Project- YAML - Azure DevOps Pipeline

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines

Right now publish test result on same proejct is working fine.

What I Have?
I have two projects in Azure DevOps, One is for Board Other is for Deployment CI/CD.
I Have cypress CI/CD pipeline which runs test and Show report Under **Test Plans > Runs**
It is working fine

```
jobs:
- job: Job_2
  displayName: 'Cypress'
  pool:
    vmImage: windows-latest
  steps:
  - checkout: self
    clean: False
  - task: Npm@1
    displayName: Install Packages
    inputs:
      workingDir: $(Build.SourcesDirectory)/Test_Project
      verbose: false
  - task: Npm@1
    displayName: Run Tests
    inputs:
      workingDir: $(Build.SourcesDirectory)/Test_Project
      command: 'custom'
      customCommand: 'run cypress:run'
     
      
  - task: PublishTestResults@2
    displayName: Publish Test Results
    inputs:
      testResultsFormat: 'JUnit'
      testResultsFiles: 'junitreport.xml'
      searchFolder: '$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/Test_Project/cypress/reports'
```

What I Need
I Need to Publsih Test Result to Another Azure DevOps Project

Comment: *I have two projects in Azure DevOps, One is for Board Other is for Deployment CI/CD.* **Why???**

Comment: Because we have multiple teams and for all deployments we have a separate DevOps Project

Comment: That's going to cause all sorts of problems, like you're discovering. Projects are intended for isolation of **unrelated** things. Your application code, your application's backlog, and your application's build and deployment process are all **highly related** things.

Comment: Yes, I know, but this the requirement. Is it possible to do?

Comment: There's no solution that you're interested in hearing. Related things should go in the same project, not different projects.